# How to export only specific folder ADF pipelines alone in azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a so many adf pipelines by multiple folder level as below

Fodler A - 10

FOLDER B - 15

FOLDER C -20
..

FOLDER N --100 etc

Is there any way can I
export only specific folder and pipelines under that folder (FODLER C- 20 pipelines ) alone.

Comment: Where do you want to export these pipelines to?

Comment: I have need of specific pipelines to move into another ADF not a complete set .So i am thinking to download to local and move to another ADF as needed.

Comment: You can use this API to do it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/get?tabs=HTTP (using any language that can call a REST API) or you can pull the pipeline definitions out of Git, if that is enabled. I have seen pipeline-specific migration frameworks online, just can't find them now.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this done using python sdk.

- Firstly, I have create a `DataFactoryManagementClient` class using the following code.

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import models

credential = ClientSecretCredential("<TENANT_ID>","<CLIENT_ID>","<CLIENT_SECRET>")

client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credential, <SUBSCRIPTION_ID>)
```

- Then I have tried to list all the pipelines from required folder  using the below code.

```
pipelines=client.pipelines.list_by_factory("<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>","<SOURCE_DATAFACTORY_NAME>")
res=[]
for i in pipelines:
    if(i.as_dict()['folder']['name']=='<YOUR_REQUIRED_FOLDER>'):
        i.id = i.id.replace('factories/<SOURCE_DATAFACTORY_NAME>','factories/<DESTINATION_DATAFACTORY_NAME>')
        print(i.as_dict())
        res.append(i.as_dict())
```

- Finally, I have created the pipeline using the below code

```
for i in res:

x = client.pipelines.create_or_update(resource_group_name="<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>",factory_name='<DESTINATION_DATAFACTORY_NAME>',pipeline_name = i['name'], pipeline = i)
```

##### RESULTS:

- Source Data factory folder

  [image]
- Destination Data factory folder

  [image]